# Файловая система внешнего HDD для Linux

Tags: linux, elementary-os

На днях взял внешний HDD на 1 ТБ. На всех машинах стоит GNU/Linux.  Форматировал внешний HDD в ext4 и прописал права

```
chown -R $USER:$USER /media/backup/
```

Столкнулся со странной проблемой.  При копирование папки из домашней папки на внешний HDD появляется ошибка:

> "Нельзя обработать папку «88», потому что у вас нет прав на её чтение."

Что за папка "88" хзДистр Elementary OS  Может стоит использовать другую файловую систему?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А вот как есть - так и есть! Папка "88", судя по всему, была создана рутовым процессом, поэтому юзеру и отказано в доступе! Вообще-то возникновение таких папок в /home/... (ну, в юзерских папках)- это очень даже подозрительно! Рутовые файлы обычно находятся только в /root и во многих общих, но никак не в папке юзера!!! На это стоит обратить внимание! Это могло там появиться, если вы у себя чего-то там из-под рута руками делали. Скорее всего (ну, если это не дрянь вирусная), то там наверняка конфиги какие-то. В любом случае её можно снести!

Answer (score 0):

У вас в домашней директории (домашней папки из которой копируете) есть каталог "[88](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/14/88)"

Найдете его `find -type d  /home/user | grep 88 | xargs ls -l`

И увидите его права, сто гульдонов на то что у вас  нет прав на его  чтение .

Исправить просто `chown +r /home/user/path/to/88`

Answer (score 0):

chown это не режим доступа к файлам, а принадлежность к пользователям и группам. Для смены режима доступа используйте chmod (напр. chmod +r). А ещё лучше почитайте про тонкости монтирования устройств и если нужно автомонтирование, то особенно про fstab.